# Giving data to programs as service

Tags: debian, java, services

A follow up of this post: [Shell script does not run java, wrong parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392935/shell-script-does-not-run-java-wrong-parameters/392945)

I've created a program in java which reads the console, and react accordingly. Now I want this program constantly run, and read data what has been entered, but this maschine has only a barcode reader as an input. When I run the program manually, it works correctly, but I cannot make it automated. I need this, because it won't have a keyboard or a monitor. When it runs as a service, it doesn't take any input, and /proc/[procid]/fd/0 always gives permission denied.

How can I run this java program, that it always restarts itself, and able to read the input from the barcode reader?

The Barcode reader acts as a Generic 104 buttons PC, Right-AltGr, No compose key.

Comment: What type of input does the barcode reader act as? a keyboard? More details on which one you are using might offer better advice.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm not sure which details are useful and which are not. It gives it's id, the read barcode as a string, and then a newline (\10\13 if I remember correctly. It behaves as it hits and enter after each message.)

Comment: What *exactly* reading the console from a Java program means? Maybe you mean that your Java program is reading from its stdin (which is not the same in general). You should give a simple Java program -similar to yours- in your question (or at least put a link to the source code of your Java program)

Comment: Are you sure that the barcoder acts like a *English* keyboard? Can you reconfigure the layout of that keyboard (e.g. with `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`)? You should read more documentation about your barcode reader!

Comment: Without much more information about that barcode reader  (what model), the drivers involved, the configuration of the computer, the specific Java program, that question is unclear and too broad.

Comment: It works normally when I use it as an English keyboard. When I use Hungarian, it gives there characters that are Hungarian where the English keys should be. (For example, ö instead 0, ü instead -).

Comment: What does it have to do with the reader? It's just like using a computer with a keyboard without a monitor. Except the input is much more limited.

Comment: Do you use any specific driver?

Comment: No, I use the one coming with the default install.

Comment: You are lacking general know-how about Linux and Unix. Take a few days to read good books (e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)....) before coding any single additional line

Comment: He means the scanner acts like a generic keyboard - basically typing out the character of the barcode scanned. Not an uncommon way for barcode readers to act. As far as linux is concerned it is a usb keyboard, no special drivers required. His application works when run in a terminal but not when disconnected from stdin - which is what his question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main ways to tackle this.

## Redirect a stdin from a tty to your application

By default systems boot to tty1, you can disable the getty running on that tty and hijack its input for your on purpose. First disable the getty on the system

```
sudo systemctl stop getty@tty1.service
sudo systemctl disable getty@tty1.service
```

You should do this from an ssh session or another getty or you will lose your login. *You didn't mention your system, but with systemd this is the way - consult your distros documentation if this does not work for you*

Now we need to create a wrapper script that contains your application to redirect `/dev/tty1` to stdin of your program (the `</dev/tty1` at the end): `/usr/local/bin/rxtxcomm`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni \
  -cp /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar -jar '/foo/bar.jar' </dev/tty1
```

And make it executable with:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rxtxcomm
```

Then update your service file to run this script instead. Restart the service and it should attach its stdin to `/dev/tty1`.

You can try it manually by running the above command in another tty or ssh session, but you need to run it as root (or changes the permissions on the tty). Note that with this solution you have to be on tty1 for it to capture any input (alt+ctrl+F1 on most systems). Also, to do this you must be root (which service files are by default) or the user you run as must have access to read from the tty directly.

## Read directly from `/dev/input/`

Almost all devices in linux are available as files inside `/dev`. Keyboards are available in `/dev/input/`. You can modify your program to instead read directly from these files - the can be read from like any files but produce binary data so it is a little more work to get the characters typed.

Here is a short java example taken from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167789/tell-java-which-keyboard-to-listen-to).

```
// replace path with path from your system
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
    new FileInputStream("/dev/input/by-id/usb-0430_0005-event-kbd"));
String map = "    abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ";
// sizeof(struct timeval) = 16
byte[] timeval = new byte[16];
short type, code;
int value;
while (true) {
    in.readFully(timeval);
    type = in.readShort();
    code = in.readShort();
    value = in.readInt();
    System.out.printf("%04x %04x %08x %c\n", type, code, value, 
                                             map.charAt(value>>>24));
}
```

This method has the advantage of attaching to a specific keyboard - so you can attach another keyboard without interfering with the script. Which can be useful for debugging the system. It also means you do not need to disable a tty or forced to be on a specific tty for the application to work. You are still required to run as root however, or changes the permissions of the devices so another user has direct access to it.

Comment: I tried to run the first one, but now the java doesn't even start running. I also tried adding exec into the shell script.
-bash: /dev/tty1: Permission denied

Comment: Did you run it as root? Did it error at all? You should not need exec in the script. Do you already have something running on tty1 (alt+ctrl+F1 to switch to that tty)?

Comment: `-bash: /dev/tty1: Permission denied` you need to run it as root to attach to a tty like this. Or changes the permissions on /dev/tty1 to allow your user to read from it.

Comment: I've done it as root. At least with sudo. Do I need to log in as root?

Comment: O, did you make the script executable?

Comment: I've added 777 permissions to it.

Comment: Did you run the script as root? or did you add sudo inside the script - the latter will not work. You need to run the entire script as root `sudo /usr/local/bin/rxtxcomm` for the redirect to work inside it.

Comment: I added a sudo. Will check running as a toor. Oooh, it works, even across the room. :D Okay, the only thing it needs now is to run it as a script, so I don't need to start the program each time after restart.

Comment: And I can't upvote posts or edit my comments, because I don't have enough reputation. I've added a sudo su - as the second line of the shell script, but it's still not running.

Comment: Like in the previous question - just replace the command in the service file with the path to the wrapper script we created.

Comment: I did, it's now ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rxtxcomm.sh
And now the whole thing froze from the daemon-reload, be right back.
And I lost it, not even restart works anymore. :(

Comment: Okay, it's working again. Apparently I can not write sudo su - into a bash script, but how exactly do I run it now as a root? https://askubuntu.com/questions/167847/how-to-run-bash-script-as-root-with-no-password I changed it's owner to root, and gave it permissions, but it's still not running. :(

Comment: Systemd will run things as root by default, no need to do anything special, you should just be able to leave sudo out of the script and ExecStart line completely.

Comment: Currently it's ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rxtxcomm.sh, and the script has only one line (and a shebang), which starts with the /usr/bin/java. At this moment, the script does not run. I added an exec in front of the script, but it's still not working.

Comment: Wrote a new shell script that uses exec sudo, and run it in root crontab each minute. Now it works as intended (altough, have to wait about a minute after start to run normally, but it's a minor setback).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have your program started at power on time.

How to do that depends upon the [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) program used by your Unix or Linux system (e.g. some systems are using [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) others are using some [sysvinit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SYSV))

If `crond` is started on your system, consider some `@reboot` entry in your [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

> How can I run this java program, that it always restarts itself, and able to read the input from the barcode reader?

A better way is to write a good enough program that does not stop unwillingly. Otherwise, wrap it into some shell script that would restart it on failure.

You need to understand how the barcode reader is viewed from Linux. Probably it is some character device, perhaps some [tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)... See [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html), [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html), [agetty(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html), [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), [kbd_mode(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kbd_mode.1.html) and read the [Tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381088/50557)

> When it runs as a service, it doesn't take any input, and /proc/[procid]/fd/0 always gives permission denied.

Because in that case stdin is not a terminal (or the keyboard, or your barcode reader). You should perhaps redirect it.

Of course programs started at power on (thru init, systemd, crontab, ...) or in batch mode (with `at` or `batch` or even `nohup`) don't have the same execution environment as your interactive command line (different file descriptors, different [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)....). You either need to take that into account when coding these programs, or code some wrapping shell script setting things well (redirecting stdin, stdout, stderr; `export`-ing some important variables)

PS. I recommend taking a few days to read more about Linux (e.g. [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [*From Power Up To Bash Prompt*](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/From-PowerUp-To-Bash-Prompt-HOWTO.html), [*Introduction to Linux*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/index.html), [*Understanding and Using `systemd`*](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-and-using-systemd), [*Bash beginners Guide*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html)) and operating systems (e.g. [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)) before coding any single line of Java or some script.

Comment: For example, yes. It uses systemd. The barcode reader acts as an English keyboard.

I haven't experienced failures so far, just want to make sure it doesn't do some funky stuff.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What happens when you `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` ?

Comment: A keyboard configurator comes up, Generic 104 buttons PC, Right-AltGr, No compose key, update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults

Comment: You should edit your question, not comment it

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I can see how somebody might think that this is “Not An Answer”.  Yes, auto-starting the program is good advice, but I don’t see where you give a *specific* answer to the question of getting the barcode data to the program.